# How to add a meesagebox to send button in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook, userform

I have created a Macro and at the end, it should send an email from Outlook by clicking the button from a "Userform". The Outlook has been called and we need to add a custom Messagebox to send button.

Answer (score 0):

To create a messagebox in VBA the code is as follows

`Msgbox("Hello World")`

add this to the click event of your send button

Comment: Hi, Maybe I have to put my question in otherway. In outlook, we have "Send" Button and i want to add a messagebox. Do you know how to Customize the "Send" Button?

Comment: Right click your button, Select "Assign Macro" and either create a new one with the code above or assign an existing one